# Install snappybundle symfony4

Tags: php, symfony4, knp-snappy

I have an installation problem with **SnappyBundle** on **Symfony 4**.
Indeed, I proceeded like this tutoriel : [Tutoriel](https://launchrocket.es/post/generar-pdf-s-con-symfony-4).

I followed the tutorial to the letter, I realized by testing the console, before making the controller with :
`php bin/console`

But I have an error, after setting up the configuration.
Here is the message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "KnpSnappyBundle" from namespace "Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projet/src/Kernel.php:33
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projet/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(409): App\Kernel-> registerBundles ()
>   1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projet/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(120): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel-> initializeBundles ()
>   2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(65): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel-> boot ()
>   3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application-> doRun (Object (Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object (Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>   4 / Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/bin/console (39 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projet/src/Kernel.php on line 33

I did add the bundle to the file `/config/packages/bundles.php`

> Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle :: class => ['all' => true],

Most of the topics on Snappy are discussed with Symfony 3, except the problem here comes from the Symfony kernel, but why, I do not understand.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome. _did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?_

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but I do not think I have forgotten, given that I have this message even before having made the controller that is supposed to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the SnappyBundle at the beginning of your controller.

For example:

```
use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\Response\Response;
```

Comment: hello, it does not change anything because the error message appears even before it is coded

Comment: Is the "use" really necessary, since we call snappy via a service ```$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')```

Answer (score 0):

I capitulated, rather than using **snappy**, I will try with **dompdf**, which looks very good and easier to set up.
solved: [Github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)
thanks for all